# Django + Gunicorn big TTFB time

Tags: python, django, optimization, time, gunicorn

I'm look at the Google Chrome console ajax request time. 
I measured at backend, the mysql query is executed for 5 ms.
At Chrome console I see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAsPL.png)

TTFB time 333.07 ms. 
I have 9 gunicorn workers, Django framework and REST framework. What takes so much time?

For example, 
my view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_gallery(request, slug):
    query = Gallery.objects.filter(route__slug=slug, route__is_active=True)

    return JSONResponse(GallerySerializer(query, many=True).data)


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

my serializer:

```
class GallerySerializer(ModelSerializerWithAuth):
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=False)
    thumb = serializers.ImageField(use_url=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ('id', 'image', 'thumb')
```

gunicorn config:

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:9090'
errorlog = '/path/to/log'
timeout=120
user = 'user'

import multiprocessing
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler?

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this question without even seeing your code ??? Should we use a crystal ball ?

Comment: @NilsWerner, what is a profiler?

Comment: Something that lets you analyze the performance of your code. Like [silk](https://github.com/django-silk/silk).

Answer (score 0):

Could be time formatting the answer. By the default, the response is build in memory and the send to the client.

A possible solution/workaround is to use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse)